# Weird margin-bottom behavior with Safari on iOS

Tags: html, ios, css, safari, margin

I have something like this in my `body` (simplified)

```
<div id="container">
  <article>
    text
  </article>
</div>
```

with the css

```
#container > article
  margin-bottom: 50px
  overflow: auto

article
  display: block
```

On all browsers the margin-bottom is displayed but Safari which seems to collapse it.

I read a lot about this issue, but the `overflow: auto` does not help right away or any other tricks.

Where things get actually weird is if I move the `margin-bottom` to the `article` definition in the css, in this case Safari displays the margin..

```
#container > article
  /* nothing remains here */

article
  display: block
  margin-bottom: 50px
  overflow: auto
```

This is not what I want since it affects **all** the `article` tags.

If someone could explains me this, and have a workaround to actually make Safari behaves as expected, that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

I experienced this on other browser as well. It seems that the margin-bottom does not work "if there is nothing to bounce from".

My solution always was to add a small padding to the parent element. Then the margin bounces on the padding.

So try adding:

```
#container {
  padding-bottom: 1px;
}
```

Comment: This does work with current Firefox but not in Safari.

Comment: This worked perfectly to fix this issue for me in Safari!

Answer (score 4):

Well instead of a margin-bottom on the element directly you could use this:

```
#container > article:after {
height: 50px;
content: "";
position: absolute;
width: 100%;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding a non-breaking-space at the bottom of the HTML worked for me:

```
<div id="container">
    <article>
        text
    </article>
</div>
&nbsp;
```